# Async database queries with CloudFlare workers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have a use case where I'm wanting to run potentially long-running queries via CloudFlare workers.  These seem to work great for the simple quick stuff, but I'm thinking about queries which could potentially take a couple of minutes.  For example, a quick query:

```js
export default {
    async fetch(
        request: Request,
        env: Env,
        ctx: ExecutionContext
    ): Promise<Response> {
        const client = new Client(env.DB_URL);
        await client.connect();

        const result = await client.query("SELECT * FROM data");

        const resp = new Response(JSON.stringify(result.rows), {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });

        ctx.waitUntil(client.end());
        return resp;
    },
};
```

I don't really want to be sat waiting for the worker to run a long query, so I'm considering something whereby the worker issues the query and sticks the results into a cache somewhere that I can poll for (so maybe this is just a JavaScript problem?)

However, this is just an idea that I've come up with.  Are there any other more 'best practice' ways of potentially solving this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use [Cloudflare Queues](https://developers.cloudflare.com/queues/). Send a job to `long-running-jobs` queue that triggers a Worker (the long running job). When the long running job is finished it sends the results to another queue (could send to multiple queues if needed) `long-running-results` that triggers a Worker that does something with the resulting data. If some error occurs, send that to `long-running-errors`.

You could extend that solution with;

- a state machine for polling, e.g.; `Queued`, `Running`, `Failed`, `Completed`. That could be built using a database ([Cloudflare D1](https://developers.cloudflare.com/d1/) - in public beta), key-value store ([Cloudflare Workers KV](https://developers.cloudflare.com/kv/)) or a strongly consistant store ([Cloudflare Durable objects](https://developers.cloudflare.com/durable-objects/)).
- storage of the resulting data in D1 or [R2](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/).

Remember that there are [limits](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#worker-limits) on the CPU time for Workers; 30 s for HTTP requests and 15 min for Queue consumers.